# create a button that pulls a table id and user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, haml

I have a page that has a list of referrals on it. I have a button on each of the referrals that is set to reply to the referral. I don't need any pop up or form to show except for a flash message to show the user has successfully replied to the referral and toggling a class on the button when a user replies. Upon replying to the referral, email(is index for the table) is passed, referralid is also passed to the reply table. I have tried many methods, but I'm getting nowhere with the controllers. I created proper associations on the models, but still getting nowhere in the controller logic to create a reply record for every reply. Here are my models:

**Referral Model**

```
  class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :referraltype
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    has_many :replies

    def nil_zero?
      self.nil? || self == 0
    end
  end
```

**User Model**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

      attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, :uid, :image

      has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x320>", thumb: "50x50" }
      has_many :referrals
      has_many :replies
    end
```

**Replies Controller**

```
  class RepliesController < ApplicationController

  end
```

**Reply Model**

```
  class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :referral
  end
```

**Referrals Controller**

```
    class ReferralsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def reply_to_referral
      @referral = Referral.find(params[:referral_id])
      @replier_id = params[:replier_id]

      @reply = @referral.replies.create(replier_id: @replier_id)
      flash[:success] = "Referral reply sent."
      redirect_to root_path
    end

      # GET /referrals
      # GET /referrals.json
      def index
        @referrals = Referral.order("created_at desc")
        @referrals

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @referrals }
        end
      end

      # GET /referrals/1
      # GET /referrals/1.json
      def show
        @referral = Referral.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @referral }
        end
      end

      # GET /referrals/new
      # GET /referrals/new.json
      def new
        @referral = current_user.referrals.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @referral }
        end
      end

      # GET /referrals/1/edit
      def edit
        @referral = current_user.referrals.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /referrals
      # POST /referrals.json
      def create
        @referral = current_user.referrals.new(params[:referral])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @referral.save
            format.html { redirect_to @referral, notice: 'Referral was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @referral, status: :created, location: @referral }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @referral.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PUT /referrals/1
      # PUT /referrals/1.json
      def update
        @referral = current_user.referrals.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @referral.update_attributes(params[:referral])
            format.html { redirect_to @referral, notice: 'Referral was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: "edit" }
            format.json { render json: @referral.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /referrals/1
      # DELETE /referrals/1.json
      def destroy
        @referral = current_user.referrals.find(params[:id])
        @referral.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to referrals_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

    end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  GemPort::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :referrals do
      resources :replies
      member do
        put "reply_to_referral"
      end
    end

    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

    root :to => 'pages#home'
    get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  end
```

**Migration for the Replies table**

```
  class CreateReplies < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :replies do |t|
        t.references :user
        t.references :referral

        t.timestamps
      end
      add_index :replies, :user_id
      add_index :replies, :referral_id
    end
  end
```

**code on the _referral.html.haml partial that is giving the error:**

```
    = link_to '<i class="icon-ok icon-large pull-right icon-grey" rel="tooltip" title="Reply"> Reply</i>'.html_safe, reply_to_referral_path(referral_id: referral.id, replier_id: current_user.id)
```

I know this must be simple to do in the controller, I tried using a helper but got nowhere

Comment: `@referral_reply = @referral.referral_replies.create(params[:referral])` won't work, since there are no `params[:referral]`, what are you actually trying to create? Which attributes? Also make sure you restart your app after changing routes.

Comment: I'm trying to put the referral.id and current_user.email into the referral reply table when the current user hits the reply button, each referral can have many replies from different users (1 reply each per user) but I will give the user the ability to limit the replies on a referral (25 lets say)

Comment: oh and I did restart the server, still the same error. I can even take out the method from the controller and I still receive the error

Comment: I've updated my code to show you how to save those attributes. Also the error you're getting is to do with the `_referral.html.haml` partial in the `index` view, I would add them both to your question. Lastly, in your `Referral` model it should be `has_many :referral_replies`

Comment: thanks, okay so I simplified the names, ended up destroying the old scaffolds models/sql table/controllers and created a new one called replies. I'm updating my code above, the only issue that it gives in the partial is the button, as soon as i take it out, the reply button, its fine.

Comment: When you first asked this question you had a `has_many` / `belongs_to` association, but now in your update it looks like a `many to many` association instead. You should read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and I recommend going through this tutorial so you understand more about RoR: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: The associations are correct, a user can have many referrals and replies, an a referral has many replies. A replier belongs to a user and a referral. I got it working by updating the path on the button to new_referral_reply_path(:referral_id => referral.id, :replier_id => current_user.id)  but now I have another issue

Answer (score 0):

Add your routes and controller and we can give you a better answer, but I'm guessing that this isn't working since you're passing an email to the route.

Emails have full stops (`.`) which can break your route unless you add constraints to the route.

Try changing your route to something like:

```
resources :referrals do
  member do
    put "reply_to_referral" # will give you referrals/:id/reply_to_referral
  end
end
```

Now change your link to `reply_to_referral_path(id: referral.id, email: current_user.email)`, this should come out as `/referrals/32/reply_to_referral?email=user@email.com`

Then in referrals controller:

```
def reply_to_referral
  @referral = Referral.find(params[:id])
  @email = params[:email]
  # now make sure your referral_replies table has a column called 'email' and
  # also one called 'referral_id', then you can do:
  @referral_reply = @referral.referral_replies.create(email: @email)
  flash[:success] = "Referral reply sent."
  redirect_to # wherever required
end
```

You could do something similar by adding  a constraint to the route, or by passing in the user's id instead of email and then querying the database.

To style the button you can then check if the referral has any replies:

```
<% if referral.referral_replies.any? %>
  # add a CSS class
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you mean to have this on the helper:  @referral_reply = @referral.referral_replies.create(params[:email])?   also getting this error:   NoMethodError in Referrals#index

undefined method `reply_to_referral' for #<#<Class:0x007fe6bfe64738>:0x007fe6bfc26d40>

Comment: also I need the referralreply with the email and referral id to write to the referralreply table, we can do this from the referral controller? I didn't think you could write through one controller to another via model but I guess we made the associations so it should work?

Comment: The first thing you wrote isn't a helper, it's code that should be in the controller `reply_to_referral` action. The second thing should be `reply_to_referral_path(...)` in the view (I made a typo). That's correct, you can access any table you wish from any controller, but obviously you don't want to make a big mess and mix code everywhere.

Comment: okay I figured the _path was missing, okay still getting NoMethodError in Referrals#index, ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `reply_to_referral_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f982589eaf8>:0x007f982583e6a8>):

Comment: Routes.rb showing 
        GemPort::Application.routes.draw do
          resources :referral_replies
          resources :referrals do
            member do
              put "reply_to_referral"
            end
          end
          devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
        end

Comment: If you're getting an error add the related view, controller and routes code to your question, it's too hard to understand in a comment.

Comment: okay added the models controllers and the routes to the question, added the link from the view, If I take off the path link it works.